# Error installing PhoneGap plugin applaud on Eclipse Kepler

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, cordova, installation, applaud

I have Eclipse Kepler installed.

I installed ADT plugin from: 
http://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/

I then tried to install the PhoneGap plugin applaud, from this link:
https://svn.codespot.com/a/eclipselabs.org/mobile-web-development-with-phonegap/tags/r1.2/download

Error occurs during the installation. The error is the following:

Problem Occurred.
'Installing software' has encountered a problem.
An error occurred while collecting items to be installed.

Error Description:

An error occurred while collecting items to be installed
session context was:(profile=epp.package.standard, phase=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.Collect, operand=, action=).
Failed to transfer artifact canonical: osgi.bundle,org.mozilla.javascript,1.7.2.v201005080400.
Retry another mirror
Problems downloading artifact: osgi.bundle,org.mozilla.javascript,1.7.2.v201005080400.
MD5 hash is not as expected. Expected: 8785860e8f2a2a43fe10dd8b9eb334b6 and found 7ab8a5d6da46b081c83bfc81e7c880e6.
Retry another mirror
Problems downloading artifact: osgi.bundle,org.mozilla.javascript,1.7.2.v201005080400.
MD5 hash is not as expected. Expected: 8785860e8f2a2a43fe10dd8b9eb334b6 and found 7ab8a5d6da46b081c83bfc81e7c880e6.
Retry another mirror
Problems downloading artifact: osgi.bundle,org.mozilla.javascript,1.7.2.v201005080400.
MD5 hash is not as expected. Expected: 8785860e8f2a2a43fe10dd8b9eb334b6 and found 7ab8a5d6da46b081c83bfc81e7c880e6.
Retry another mirror
Problems downloading artifact: osgi.bundle,org.mozilla.javascript,1.7.2.v201005080400.
MD5 hash is not as expected. Expected: 8785860e8f2a2a43fe10dd8b9eb334b6 and found 7ab8a5d6da46b081c83bfc81e7c880e6.
Retry another mirror
Problems downloading artifact: osgi.bundle,org.mozilla.javascript,1.7.2.v201005080400.
MD5 hash is not as expected. Expected: 8785860e8f2a2a43fe10dd8b9eb334b6 and found 7ab8a5d6da46b081c83bfc81e7c880e6.
Retry another mirror
Problems downloading artifact: osgi.bundle,org.mozilla.javascript,1.7.2.v201005080400.
MD5 hash is not as expected. Expected: 8785860e8f2a2a43fe10dd8b9eb334b6 and found 7ab8a5d6da46b081c83bfc81e7c880e6.
Retry another mirror
Problems downloading artifact: osgi.bundle,org.mozilla.javascript,1.7.2.v201005080400.
MD5 hash is not as expected. Expected: 8785860e8f2a2a43fe10dd8b9eb334b6 and found 7ab8a5d6da46b081c83bfc81e7c880e6.
Retry another mirror
Problems downloading artifact: osgi.bundle,org.mozilla.javascript,1.7.2.v201005080400.
MD5 hash is not as expected. Expected: 8785860e8f2a2a43fe10dd8b9eb334b6 and found 7ab8a5d6da46b081c83bfc81e7c880e6.
Retry another mirror
Problems downloading artifact: osgi.bundle,org.mozilla.javascript,1.7.2.v201005080400.
MD5 hash is not as expected. Expected: 8785860e8f2a2a43fe10dd8b9eb334b6 and found 7ab8a5d6da46b081c83bfc81e7c880e6.
Retry another mirror
Problems downloading artifact: osgi.bundle,org.mozilla.javascript,1.7.2.v201005080400.
MD5 hash is not as expected. Expected: 8785860e8f2a2a43fe10dd8b9eb334b6 and found 7ab8a5d6da46b081c83bfc81e7c880e6.
Retry another mirror
Problems downloading artifact: osgi.bundle,org.mozilla.javascript,1.7.2.v201005080400.
MD5 hash is not as expected. Expected: 8785860e8f2a2a43fe10dd8b9eb334b6 and found 7ab8a5d6da46b081c83bfc81e7c880e6.
Retry another mirror
Problems downloading artifact: osgi.bundle,org.mozilla.javascript,1.7.2.v201005080400.
MD5 hash is not as expected. Expected: 8785860e8f2a2a43fe10dd8b9eb334b6 and found 7ab8a5d6da46b081c83bfc81e7c880e6.
Retry another mirror
Problems downloading artifact: osgi.bundle,org.mozilla.javascript,1.7.2.v201005080400.
MD5 hash is not as expected. Expected: 8785860e8f2a2a43fe10dd8b9eb334b6 and found 7ab8a5d6da46b081c83bfc81e7c880e6.
Retry another mirror
Problems downloading artifact: osgi.bundle,org.mozilla.javascript,1.7.2.v201005080400.
MD5 hash is not as expected. Expected: 8785860e8f2a2a43fe10dd8b9eb334b6 and found 7ab8a5d6da46b081c83bfc81e7c880e6.
Retry another mirror
Problems downloading artifact: osgi.bundle,org.mozilla.javascript,1.7.2.v201005080400.
MD5 hash is not as expected. Expected: 8785860e8f2a2a43fe10dd8b9eb334b6 and found 7ab8a5d6da46b081c83bfc81e7c880e6.
Retry another mirror
Problems downloading artifact: osgi.bundle,org.mozilla.javascript,1.7.2.v201005080400.
MD5 hash is not as expected. Expected: 8785860e8f2a2a43fe10dd8b9eb334b6 and found 7ab8a5d6da46b081c83bfc81e7c880e6.
Retry another mirror
Problems downloading artifact: osgi.bundle,org.mozilla.javascript,1.7.2.v201005080400.
MD5 hash is not as expected. Expected: 8785860e8f2a2a43fe10dd8b9eb334b6 and found 7ab8a5d6da46b081c83bfc81e7c880e6.
Retry another mirror
Problems downloading artifact: osgi.bundle,org.mozilla.javascript,1.7.2.v201005080400.
MD5 hash is not as expected. Expected: 8785860e8f2a2a43fe10dd8b9eb334b6 and found 7ab8a5d6da46b081c83bfc81e7c880e6.
Retry another mirror
Problems downloading artifact: osgi.bundle,org.mozilla.javascript,1.7.2.v201005080400.
MD5 hash is not as expected. Expected: 8785860e8f2a2a43fe10dd8b9eb334b6 and found 7ab8a5d6da46b081c83bfc81e7c880e6.
Retry another mirror
Problems downloading artifact: osgi.bundle,org.mozilla.javascript,1.7.2.v201005080400.
MD5 hash is not as expected. Expected: 8785860e8f2a2a43fe10dd8b9eb334b6 and found 7ab8a5d6da46b081c83bfc81e7c880e6.
Retry another mirror
Problems downloading artifact: osgi.bundle,org.mozilla.javascript,1.7.2.v201005080400.
MD5 hash is not as expected. Expected: 8785860e8f2a2a43fe10dd8b9eb334b6 and found 7ab8a5d6da46b081c83bfc81e7c880e6.
Retry another mirror
Problems downloading artifact: osgi.bundle,org.mozilla.javascript,1.7.2.v201005080400.
MD5 hash is not as expected. Expected: 8785860e8f2a2a43fe10dd8b9eb334b6 and found 7ab8a5d6da46b081c83bfc81e7c880e6.
Retry another mirror
Problems downloading artifact: osgi.bundle,org.mozilla.javascript,1.7.2.v201005080400.
MD5 hash is not as expected. Expected: 8785860e8f2a2a43fe10dd8b9eb334b6 and found 7ab8a5d6da46b081c83bfc81e7c880e6.
Retry another mirror
Problems downloading artifact: osgi.bundle,org.mozilla.javascript,1.7.2.v201005080400.
MD5 hash is not as expected. Expected: 8785860e8f2a2a43fe10dd8b9eb334b6 and found 7ab8a5d6da46b081c83bfc81e7c880e6.
Retry another mirror
Problems downloading artifact: osgi.bundle,org.mozilla.javascript,1.7.2.v201005080400.
MD5 hash is not as expected. Expected: 8785860e8f2a2a43fe10dd8b9eb334b6 and found 7ab8a5d6da46b081c83bfc81e7c880e6.
Retry another mirror
Problems downloading artifact: osgi.bundle,org.mozilla.javascript,1.7.2.v201005080400.
MD5 hash is not as expected. Expected: 8785860e8f2a2a43fe10dd8b9eb334b6 and found 7ab8a5d6da46b081c83bfc81e7c880e6.
Retry another mirror
Problems downloading artifact: osgi.bundle,org.mozilla.javascript,1.7.2.v201005080400.
MD5 hash is not as expected. Expected: 8785860e8f2a2a43fe10dd8b9eb334b6 and found 7ab8a5d6da46b081c83bfc81e7c880e6.
Retry another mirror
Problems downloading artifact: osgi.bundle,org.mozilla.javascript,1.7.2.v201005080400.
MD5 hash is not as expected. Expected: 8785860e8f2a2a43fe10dd8b9eb334b6 and found 7ab8a5d6da46b081c83bfc81e7c880e6.
Retry another mirror
Problems downloading artifact: osgi.bundle,org.mozilla.javascript,1.7.2.v201005080400.
MD5 hash is not as expected. Expected: 8785860e8f2a2a43fe10dd8b9eb334b6 and found 7ab8a5d6da46b081c83bfc81e7c880e6.
Retry another mirror
Problems downloading artifact: osgi.bundle,org.mozilla.javascript,1.7.2.v201005080400.
MD5 hash is not as expected. Expected: 8785860e8f2a2a43fe10dd8b9eb334b6 and found 7ab8a5d6da46b081c83bfc81e7c880e6...